# How to bevel a misbehaving corner?

Tags: modeling, bevel

I want to add a simple rounded corner to this mesh, so I selected the corner and used ctrl + B to bevel it, but it bevels really strangely, it is very deformed.

Any idea what is wrong with it?[image]

Blend file: https://files.fm/u/c5gd2hhc

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mesh topology is not good. You have inside faces (look **into** your mesh) – delete these.

[image: inside faces]

Comment: That was it! I had to delete them one by one tho, is there some tool to delete all hidden faces like that automatically?

Comment: With *Remove Doubles* you can merge vertices that are on the same position, and in Edit Mode with Ctrl+Shift+Alt+M you can check for non manifold faces. Apart from that, I'm not aware of an automatic function to delete inside faces. I guess it's not easy for an algorithm to decide something like that.